# Why is the Laplace expansion used to calculate NXN inverse matrix when Gaussian elimination is easier and more intuitive?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering after finding an inverse matrix using Gaussian elimination why the Laplace expansion method using determinants are used? That being said I was not able to find on the internet a proof of the NXN case of the Laplace expansion using determinants.  Is there a straightforward method perhaps to demonstrate this in which case then it would be equally intuitive for me like the Gaussian elimination method. There is a lot of manipulation going on in the Laplace forming the adjunct matrix and manipulating the signs of the determinants which appear to be not very intuitive or perhaps my lack of knowledge that a clear proof may help. Thank you.

Comment: Not all methods of computation have efficiency as their aim. Sometimes a calculation can give insight into mathematical *structure* even if the calculation is not easy to carry out explicitly. In particular, the Laplace expansion shows in a direct way that the determinant of a square matrix is a *polynomial* in the matrix entries, and this is useful for theoretical considerations in certain parts of abstract algebra.

Comment: This is hardly a historic question. But one advantage of the matrix procedure is that you have not always to write the $x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Having an efficient algorithm is not always the primary goal. If you actually have to *compute* an inverse of a concrete matrix I agree, gaussian elimination (along with cholesky etc.) is the way to go. But if you want to prove something about a matrix or it's properties the laplace expansion can be very handy, as it allows for easy inductive proofs.

Consider following statement, and think of how easy it is to prove with the laplace expansion, and how cumbersome that would be with the gaussian elimination:

- If $A \in \mathbb Z^{n \times n}$ and $\det A =\pm 1$ then $A^{-1} \in \mathbb Z^{n \times n}$.